# RGB colour from 0-1 to 0-255 conversion - intensity probability distribution

Tags: colors, rgb, probability-density

I'm wondering, if I (and everyone on the internet and in the companies I've worked for) have been converting colours in a wrong way. Obviously, when I want to convert a colour from a 0-255 range to 0-1, I simply divide the values by 255, right? And when I want to go the other way, I multiply.

But is that correct? Imagine that my colours are a result of some maths (as simple as a bilinear interpolation or as complex as you might wish (or dare). Then this might not be the best way. From a certain point of view, when converting from floating point 0-1 to an integer 0-255, I want to split the interval into 256 chunks **of the same size** and then do a "lookup". If I just multiply by 255 ([rgb values to 0 to 1 scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848990/rgb-values-to-0-to-1-scale)) and round, the "chunks" or "bins" for 0 and 255 will be only half the size of the others. I.e. the probability distribution of the colour intensities won't be correct.

I don't think this is often an issue in practise. E.g. in high-end VFX, floating point colours (0-1 plus superblacks/superwhites) are always used and converted to 0-255 only as the very last step. It still bothers me though. What is the correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not necessarily the case, lets visualize this by using 2 bits quantization (4 levels):

if we divide by 4 (equivalent of 256 in 8 bits)

```
0.00 to 0.24 = Black  
0.25 to 0.49 = Dark Gray  
0.50 to 0.74 = Light Gray  
0.75 to 0.99 = White
```

You can notice that the bins are separated equally (size of 0.25), if we multiply by 256 everything would be correct. With the exception of 1.0, which would map to 256. We can fix this by clamping the values from 0 to 255.

```
if (value > 255) {
    value = 255
}
```

But if we want to simplify calculations and avoid the need of clamping, we can divide by 3 (equivalent of 255 in 8 bits)

```
0.000 to 0.333 = Black  
0.334 to 0.666 = Dark Gray  
0.667 to 0.999 = Light Gray  
1.000 to 1.333 = White
```

The common misconception is that the last bin (pure white) is only mapped to the singular value of 1.0, but it is not true, it extends up to:

```
4/3     = 1.33333 for 2 bits
256/255 = 1.00392 for 8 bits
```

For mathematical calculations, treat 1.0 to 1.00392 as pure white, and 0 to 0.00392 as pure black, and all the bins should be of equal size (0.00392).

Note: using `Math.round(value * 255)` is wrong if we use this representation!
It will lead to wrong colors being displayed, and all the bins will be shifted to the left by half of their size.
You should be using `Math.floor(value * 255)`, or even a direct cast to int `(int)(value * 255)`.

However, if you want the values to represent the median of the bins, you can use Math.round(). However the new bins will be:

```
-0.166 to 0.166 = Black  
 0.167 to 0.500 = Dark Gray  
 0.501 to 0.833 = Light Gray  
 0.834 to 1.166 = White
```

Just choose one representation and stick with it. If you use different representations throughout your code, make sure you do the appropriate conversions.

I recommend using the Median Bins if you are doing correct and accurate scientific calculations (eg. interpolation, clustering, etc), otherwise casting a  float into an int is much faster and is more suitable for fast graphical operations.

Comment: I really like the first idea, multiplying by 4 (256), flooring and clamping instead of 3 (255) and rounding - so simple and elegant, and the "bins" are exactly equally sized! (how did I not think of that myself?!?)

With the second half, I'm a bit less enthusiastic, simple for the reason that the range 0-1 feels rather "canonical" to me, i.e. we shouldn't be looking to the outside when converting to another "standard" range. Surely when looking at value 0 (8-bit), anyone would imagine it transfer from an interval [0;0.0039] rather than [-0.0020;0.0020]?

Comment: Sure, [0, 0.9999...] feels "canonical", since it is used frequently. Eg. uniform generators are usually in the [0, 0.999...] range and inverse CDF transforms usually also take an input of [0, 0.999...], so if you are working with scientific problems this representation is preferred. But if you are doing fast graphical computations (eg in games) where precision is not that important, the [0, 1.00392] trick is useful when you don't want out of bound values (1 * 256 overflows if using unsigned 8-bit values).

Comment: The benefit of using median values is shown in this example: if you have two values (0 and 1.9) and get their median value, that would be 0.95, which is closer to 1 than 0. 
Now if 2 was white and 0 black, the median of 0 and 1.9 should be a color similar to gray (1), but with flooring, it is black (0).

So rounding is preferred in this case compared to flooring.

Answer (score 1):

to get the correct result you have to multiply it by 255.(999...) and then floor it to int, otherwise you will get wrong values at the crucial points of 1/4 1/2 and 3/4 etc... -- you cannot include a subtractor because this will lead to negative values at x near 0 values.
The previous answer simply reverts that by ceiling the top values what will in return then result in wrong results near x = 1...

This is the most simple answer i found to work correctly... regards

credits: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=78108.msg590057#msg590057

Comment: A fair point, and I like the simplicity of it. An objection, though - who decides what's the "right" and "wrong" values for 1/4, 1/2 etc.?